# Multiple Comment Box moderation with different Facebook App ID

Tags: facebook

I installed Facebook Comment Plugin for a comment box. For this, I used this meta tag related to Facebook App ID

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="228435337504344" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://bdlacne.byethost24.com/Dr.Thakur/" />
```

JavaScript SDK

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;  js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And for comment box

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://bdlacne.byethost24.com/FacebookSocialPlugins/?ckattempt=1" data-numposts="5" data-order-by="time" ></div>
```

And it works fine with moderation tool.

Now I want to add another comment box (on another article and on the same page) tied with another App ID as I can set different moderation settings for each.

My query is how I can tie the multiple comment box with different App ID.

Comment: If you want different comment boxes, you need to point them to different URLs anyway. Assuming your articles have an individual URL each, place the meta tag under that URL, and then point the comments plugin to it.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe. I think I have to study more in this regard :) and then it'll be clear to me. I draw your kind attention to an another issue I found. Here is a page where I have practiced with facebook social plugins. Everything is OK except the like button(under "Facebook Like Button" the first article) and comment box (under "
Facebook Comment Plugin", the seventh article). The like button does not work and the comment box does not post any comment. I could not find the problem. Could you please have a look ? http://bdlacne.byethost24.com/FacebookSocialPlugins/?ckattempt=1

Comment: Go check your browser’s console.

Comment: Checked and didn't find any console error :( .